# pyplot.bar for long scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to plot a bar which has 116 index. Numbers and lines overlap.

I tried to reduce bar witdh, but it doesnt solve my problem.

```
width = 0.4

indices = np.arange(len(degreeCent))

plt.bar(indices, degreeCent, width=width,align='center',
        color='b', label='Degree')

plt.xticks(indices + width,
           ['T{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(degreeCent))])

plt.legend()

plt.savefig("barplot.png")
```

And the result is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Z0B.jpg

Comment: What if you increase the width of the figure inside which your bar plot is? You could declare your figure and axis this way `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 10))`

Comment: You can also rotate the labels.